# how to search highlight count occurences using angular pipes

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, search, angular-pipe

I have below angular pipe code to search and highlight the text

Let's suppose pets.description has huge  description text in below html file

```
 <div class="search-input">
     <label for="">Search here: </label> <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" type="search">
    </div>
    
    <div class="text-contaniner" [innerHtml]="text"  >
  </div>
```

and

```
export class AppComponent {
  searchText='';
  text=`somedummy text here`
}
```

style.css

```
   .highlight {
      background-color: violet;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

below is the actual pipe created

```
 transform(value: any, args: any): unknown {
      if(!args) return value;
      const re = new RegExp("\\b("+args+"\\b)", 'igm');
      value= value.replace(re, '<span class="highlighted-text">$&</span>');
      return value;
  }
```

This code searches the text and hihglights it.How do I also `show the count occurrence of matches` apart from highlighting the texts.

Comment: `value.match(re).length` (before change the value). Then you can return an object with text and count properties:`return {text:value,count:count}`. see a [little stackblit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syl2kp?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fhight.pipe.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css). NOTE: You forget `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` your value in the directive.

Comment: @Eliseo - You can put your answer below here so that I can accept it

Comment: don't worry about this. For some reason that I don't agree your question was closed. I'm pleasure if I can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per input from @Eliseo below transform function will help to get the count as well.

```
transform(value: any, args: any): unknown {
  
  if(!args) return value;
  
  count = value.match(re).length;
  const re = new RegExp("\\b("+args+"\\b)", 'igm');
  value= value.replace(re, '<span class="highlighted-text">$&</span>');
  
  return {text:value,count:count};

}
```